# Hyperlink problems

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, reporting-services, hyperlink

I want to make the following text entirely into a hyperlink together. I have the first two lines as one hyperlink. How to add the third line and then make a hyperlink.

"window.open('http://dotsd1oitdev/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2f4P%2f4P%2fProject+Status+(Selected+Projects)&PROJECT_IDS="

& l & "&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&rc:NoHeader=true');"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Comment: What happens when you append the third line to the end of the second one and make the Javascript call? Does it work? I see that you have `:` characters in your query string; I am not sure if that will cause some problems.

Comment: l is the list of the project id's selected and & rs is the PDF Format while displaying the report